Dimension of Compact Subspace of a Topological Manifold.
Whenever I say "dimension", it always refers to the Lebesgue covering dimension.
Here is an exercise in Munkres' book Topology at page 315.

Theorem 1. Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable basis, such that every compact subspace of $X$ has dimension at most $m$. Then $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\Bbb R^{2m+1}$.

Then he claimed this theorem has the following corollary.

Corollary 2. Every $m$-manifold can be imbedded in $\Bbb R^{2m+1}$ as a closed subspace.

I do not understand why this is an immediate corollary of the previous theorem. One really needs to know every compact subspace of an $m$-manifold has topological dimension at most $m$.
There is a relevant theorem in the same section, and I listed it below.

Theorem 3. Every compact subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ has dimension at most $n$.

Can anyone help?
Update: I think I just solved it after typing the question down again and re-thought about it...

Here is my attempt. If $K$ is a compact subspace of the $m$-manifold $M$, then for every point $k\in K$ choose by $m$-locally Euclidean an open neighborhood $k\in U_k\subset M$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. Choose an open set $V_k$ containing $k$ such that $V_k$ is an open ball in the homeomorphic image in $\Bbb R^n$. Then $\overline{V_k}$ is compact as it corresponds to the closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$, thus finite-dimensional as a homeomorphic image of a finite-dimensional compact ball. Consider the open cover of $K$ by these $V_k$ and choose then a finite subcover. The dimension of the finite union $$C=\bigcup_{i=1}^r \overline{V_k}$$ is finite, and $K$ is a closed subspace of $C$. Thus by Theorem 50.1 in Munkres' book Topology, $K$ must have finite dimension as well, as needed.

If you've solved your own question, please post the proof as an answer and accept it instead of as part of the question itself so that this doesn't have to go unanswered :)

@BenSteffan Got it! I will do it now.

There are three theorems that I will using, and they are all in Section 50 of Munkres' book Topology, second edition. I quoted them all below.

Theorem 50.1. Let $X$ be a space having finite dimension. If $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$, then $Y$ has finite dimension and $\dim Y\leq \dim X$.


Corollary 50.3. Let $X=Y_1\cup...\cup Y_k$, where each $Y_i$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and is finite dimensional. Then $\dim X=\max\{\dim Y_1,...,\dim Y_k\}$.


Theorem 50.6. Every compact subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ has topological dimension at most $n$.

Now let $K$ be a compact subspace of the $m$-manifold $M$. For every point $k\in K$ choose by $m$-locally Euclidean an open neighborhood $k\in U_k\subset M$ homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$. Choose an open set $V_k\subset U_k$ containing $k$ such that the homeomorphic image of $V_k$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is an open ball around the image of $k$. Then $\overline{V_k}$ corresponds to the closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$, which is finite-dimensional by Theorem 50.6 . Then $\overline{V_k}$ must be finite-dimensional as a homeomorphic image of this closed ball.
Consider then the open cover of $K$ by these $V_k$ as $k$ ranges all of $K$ and choose a finite subcover $V_1,...,V_r$. The dimension of the finite union $$C=\bigcup_{i=1}^r \overline{V_k}$$ is finite by Corollary 50.3. Moreover, $K$ is a closed subspace of $C$. Thus by Theorem 50.1, $K$ must have finite dimension as well, as needed.
